# How To Use R script on Uploaded files (2) in R Shiny and Download the New Data Frame

Tags: r, shiny

I have looked all over and could not find an example of someone using an R script on uploaded files in R Shiny and proceeding to download the new file/dataframe that resulted from that "transformation". I am not that familiar with R Shiny syntax and need to know how and where to place code that operates an R script on 2 uploaded datasets that will act as 2 dataframes that will be altered and changed in the R script and ultimately become one dataframe that I will want to download/export after the R script is finished. Any help is appreciated thanks.

The only question I saw that was similar to the one I have is "Can R Shiny be used to import file, run R script, and export file?" but the answer did not include an example of an R script being operated/performed on the uploaded dataset(s) and the download resulted in a .html file when I would like a .xlsx file.

Comment: The link to the question I referenced is: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52950971/can-r-shiny-be-used-to-import-file-run-r-script-and-export-file

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you need. Your question is not different from the link you provided, since I can only tell you that it is practically possible.
If you can provide the R script that should be run then I can setup a simple app.